# VS Code and HTML formatting: Indent <html>, <head>, <body> and <body>'s children at the same level

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I like to indent `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` and the child elements (not all descendants) of `<body>` at the same level, at the very start of each line. Like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Example</h1>

<ul>
    <li>Example 1</li>
    <li>Example 2</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I also don't want any empty lines between `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags, which is what happens by default when I run the selection formatting operation. Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Example</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Example 1</li>
        <li>Example 2</li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I configure Visual Studio Code to do this automatically?

Currently I have to manually undo the extra indentations for every new HTML file. After removing them and adding one child element to `<body>`, it does behave like I want. But it's still quite irritating to have to do it every time.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html#_formatting

Comment: @ifconfig Yes, couldn't find anything that works.